# the temporary save folder is wrong

Tags: customization, uploads, wp-config

when i try to upload image or add plugin to my wordpress website i get this errer

> the temporary save folder is wrong

i try to fix this by creating temp folder in wp-content and fixing wp-config.php by adding this colde line

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/temp/');
```

but stay get the same errer, what i can do to fix this?

Comment: Hi Hocine, Did you also check permissions on that folder?

Comment: @anmari Yes i checked the permission the folder has 755 permission

Comment: ... and it's owned by the user that the web server / PHP is running as? The 7 is the only one of the three that has write permissions, so right group isn't enough.

Comment: @anmari should i change it to 777?

Comment: You could as an experiment, but if it works you shouldn't leave it that way. You should work out what user or group WordPress is running as and give one of them permissions to write to the folder, not leave it world writable.